# multiple instances of a viewController to reference in a different viewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

I have a viewController which takes details of a product and calculates the price.
The User can calculate the price and add that product to cart. Here I was simply adding self to the array defined in cart.h and user can  continue to be on the same screen, calculate price for another product and add to cart. If I have added 3 different products to the cart, in the cartViewController I see 3 products added, but  the details of all the 3 products is the same(i.e. details of the 3rd products are shown)

Is there any way by which I can keep track of what product I am adding?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Details : 
I have a product screen. There are 5 textfields which take in values and calculate final price. User can tap "Add to Cart" to add the details of this product to the cart and continue on the same screen to find the price of next product by changing the textfield values. Once again the user taps on "Add to Cart" to add details of the new product and so on. When user taps of "View Cart" he should see all the products he had added, but I see only the last product added multiple times, i.e. every time I add a new product, it overwrites the previous products as well. So, as a result I am only able to see the last product the no.of times I tapped "Add to Cart"

Please help.

Comment: Show the add to cart code.

Comment: Can you post some code where you are adding data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found a workaround for it.
I am creating a model class and creating a new instance of that class every time I need to add an instance of the viewController to the array.

May be it is not the optimum way but it is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using an instance variable to build the cart item and adding it to the array. Then you're editing it and adding it again. And again.

You should be creating a new cart item each time and adding the new item. Then you won't edit it the next time the button is tapped.

Comment: I was basically adding the viewController to the array...so how can I add different instances ?

Comment: You shouldn't add the view controller. You should add another object (like a dictionary) that contains the required data.